# How can I change the radio button 'selected' state appearance?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, prestashop

I have customized the radio buttons for the product attributes on a Prestashop store but now the selected size does not change appearance (desired `background:#000;color:#fff`) when selected.

Product page here: http://catwalk-boutique.ro/pantofi/11-pantofi-piele-4578-burgundy.html

What I want to find out is either where to edit the "selected" state of the radio button or what could block the display of the selected state (if that is the case).

Below are the bits of code altered so far:
• in product.tpl:

```
{elseif ($group.group_type == 'radio')}
   <ul style="padding-left:5px">{assign var=groupquantity value= $group.attributes_quantity}
      {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
          <li>
              <input id="radio_{$groupName|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}-{$id_attribute}" type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="{$groupName|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" value="{$id_attribute}" {if ($group.default == $id_attribute)} checked="checked"{/if} />
              <label for="radio_{$groupName|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}-{$id_attribute}" data-comb-quantity="{*$groupquantity[$id_attribute]*}{foreach from=$combinations item=foo}{if $group_attribute == $foo.attributes_values[2]}{$foo.quantity}{/if}{/foreach}" class="radio_btn_round" >{$group_attribute|replace:' EU':''|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</label>
          </li>
      {/foreach}
   </ul>
{/if}
```

• and the CSS:

```
label.radio_btn_round {
background-color: #F8F8F8;
border: 1px solid #C8CCD2;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle!important;
line-height: 29px;}

input.attribute_radio {display: none;}
```

Any ideas are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are looking for the `:checked` pseudo class?

Comment: Given the markup the PrestaShop is creating, I don't think it's possible.  The input is buried within a span inside of a hidden div, and although you could theoretically get the "checked" element from the span (Gets a class of "checked"), there's no CSS technique for getting the *parent* of a given element and navigating to the selector.  You would have to do this with javascript / jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The markup that Prestashop has generated for this makes this not possible with straight CSS:

```
<li>
    <div>
         <span class="checked"><input value="37" selected></span>
    </div>
    <label>37</label>
</li>
```

CSS has no way of going "up" the DOM (selecting the parent `div` or `li` from the "selected" radio button).

Because jQuery is available on your site, I think your best bet is to add some light jQuery that can do this for you, and provide a class on the label which you can then address via CSS:

```
// wait until the document is ready
jQuery(function($) {
    // watch for changes to the radio inputs
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
        $('.attribute_list li')
            // remove the class from all li elements
            .removeClass('checked')
            // find the "checked" radio button
            .find('input[type="radio"]:checked')
            // go up the dom to the nearest li
            .closest('li')
            // and add the "checked" class
            .addClass('checked');
    });
});
```

Then, in your CSS, this selector will allow you to change the styles you want:

```
li.checked label.radio_btn_round {
    background: #000;
    color: white;
}
```